# Switching back to the MenuScreen in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've just started learning libgdx development. And I'm trying to add Facebook login button(custom) in my MenuScreen.java (which is in core module).

Now I've followed couple of tutorials to add facebook in libgdx, like these https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio/ & https://thecoding.pro/2015/08/30/facebook-integration-with-libgdk-on-android/.

I have implemented interface (FbServices) in AndroidLauncher. FbServices interface is in core module. And Now I am able to do facebook login. But after login, I want my MenuScreen to appear, which somehow couldn't do. So, **Question is** **how to switch back to MenuScreen after successful login?**

I'm using setScreen to show splashScreen, then in SplashScreen.java, using setScreen(new MenuScreen(this)); for switching to MenuScreen. Also If there is any other better way to manage screen please guide me.

Here is AndroidLauncher

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements FbServices {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginManager loginManager;
    private AccessToken accessToken;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        setupFacebook();
        initialize(new ZBGame(this), config);
    }    
    private void setupFacebook() {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
        loginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }    
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }    
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured!!! Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }    
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }    
    @Override
    public void signIn() {
        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
    }    
    @Override
    public void signOut() {loginManager.logOut();}    
    @Override
    public boolean isSignedIn() {
        return accessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;}
}
```

Here is my MainGame.java

```
public class MainGame extends Game {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    public FbServices fbServices;    
    public ZBGame(FbServices fbServices) {
        this.fbServices = fbServices;
    }
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        AssetLoader.load();
//      menuScreen = new MenuScreen(this);
//      gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
//      scoreScreen = new ScoreScreen(this);
        setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        super.dispose();
        AssetLoader.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly by `finish()` you can go back to previous Activity.

---

LibGDX is cross platform gaming framework so it's better to use [gdx-facebook](https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook), This is libGDX extension providing cross-platform support for Facebook Graph API.

Hopefully this may be useful.

Comment: you should call `setupFacebook()` through interfacing after initialisation by core module

Comment: No success. Not even rendered the MenuScreen for  the first time. Just Black Screen. In logcat: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. and facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifeCycleTracker: Unexpected activity pause without a matching activity resume. Logging data may be incorrect. call activeApp from applicaion's onCreate method.

Comment: why don't you try `gdx-facebook`

Comment: I really don't know. I just want to check whether it is working in Libgdx or not. And I can't find a single tutorial about this, may be no one has even tried it. I already checked many libgdx sample games, seems to avoid using it.